# Is there an sql code to set a column equal something based on two columns

Tags: sql

I work on a table where I have unique deal ids and their respective claim dues. I want to set the third column equal to 'x' if the sum of the claim due is less than $1000 for each unique id.

```
ds_id   Clm_due Review
4556    200 
4556    200 
4556    200 
5555    500 
5555    500 
5555    100 
6666    20  
6666    20  
6666    600
```

For instance if ds_id (4556) Clm_due is less than $1,000 I want Review to have the value 'x' in the third column.

I tried it in sql with the following code, but ti think I am way off the mark

```
Update myTable set Review ="X" where ds_id and Sum(Clm_due)<1000
```

Comment: Don't store data that is a computed from other table data, it will only lead to data inconsistency. Create a view instead - it will always be up to date! (Or, at least use triggers.)

Comment: @jarlh Kirix Strata

Comment: Kirix Strata can connect to different dbms products. Which one are you connected to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this DML.

```
Update myTable
Set Review='X'
From
(select ds_id, sum(Clm_due) as sm From myTable group by ds_id) as t1
Where t1.ds_id = myTable.ds_id and t1.Sm < 1000
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by ds_id to get the totals for each ds_id and join to the table in the update statement:

```
update myTable m inner join (
  select ds_id, sum(Clm_due) total
  from myTable
  group by ds_id
) t on t.ds_id = m.ds_id
set Review = 'X' 
where t.total < 1000
```

The syntax may differ for various databases.
This syntax works for MySql.
See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=49fe1483d534db4cc698551df4c14ad7).
Results:

```
> ds_id | Clm_due | Review
> ----: | ------: | :-----
>  4556 |     200 | X     
>  4556 |     200 | X     
>  4556 |     200 | X     
>  5555 |     500 |   
>  5555 |     500 |   
>  5555 |     100 |   
>  6666 |      20 | X     
>  6666 |      20 | X     
>  6666 |     600 | X
```

Answer (score 0):

A syntax that should work in any database is:

```
update mytable
    set Review = 'X' 
    where ds_id in (select t2.ds_id 
                    from mytable t2
                    group by t2.ds_id
                    having sum(clm_due) < 1000
                   );
```

I say "should" because although this is standard SQL, MySQL does not accept it.

Comment: I am trying that on my database using SQL console, could you please let me know what am i doing wrong? 
Update /Users/asalee01/TBL_SCAN_Q3 set Clm_rvw = 'X' from (select ds_id, sum(Clm_due) as sm from /Users/asalee01/TBL_SCAN_Q3 group by ds_id) as t1 where t1.ds_id = /Users/asalee01/TBL_SCAN_Q3.ds_id and t1.sm < 1000

Comment: @Akbar . . . Did you try this syntax?

Comment: yep the one that i pasted above

Comment: Users/asalee01/TBL_SCAN_Q3 is the pathway to my table on Kirix Strata